# Using global names starting with "_" in Chameleon template engine

Tags: python, chameleon

While upgrading chameleon template engine to version 2 ,  I've got errors like:

```
 NameError: global name '_c' is not defined
```

where '_c' is used as a variable in template like:

```
 tal:content="_c(item['category']"
```

in chameleon 1.2 everything was ok. 
Is there any way to make it working without changing all names starting from "_" in templates?

Comment: What version of Python are you using? Did you change any other libraries?

Comment: python 2.7
yes - I changed chameleon/zpt/template.py to ensure utf-8 encoding

Comment: The issue has been fixed in new chameleon version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That was a bug.

New versions of chameleon fix this.